# Webbrowser InvokeScript function is blocking UI thread in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, javascript, multithreading, windows-phone-8

I am invoking a Javascript function using Webbrowser in Windows Phone 8.

```
browserControl.InvokeScript(funtionName, args);
```

This javascipt function is internally calling a service to fetch the data, during the javascript call i am showing ProgressIndicator.

But i am not able to see ProgressIndicator because javascript call is stopping UI thread.

**This problem may be because of Javascript function and my UI thread is running in same thread. So i tried to move my Javascript function call to Background thread, but it failed saying "Invalid cross thread Access"**

**I am able to see the UI after my ScriptNotify is invoked. Before that i am not able to see my UI**

You can see my code snippets below:

**Can any one please suggest me how can i overcome this problem?**

My progress indicator code:

```
public void ActivateProgressIndicator(this PhoneApplicationPage currentPage, string progressIndicatorText)
        {
            ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
            progressIndicator.Text = progressIndicatorText;
            progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(currentPage, progressIndicator);
        }
```

My JS fucnction is calling a WCF rest service internally, this function call will take 30 seconds 1 minute. And i am JS code to Background thread like below:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                WebBrowser browserControl = new WebBrowser();
                browserControl.IsScriptEnabled = true;
                browserControl.Navigate(new Uri("/WebAssets/Main.html", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                browserControl.InvokeScript("RetrieveAccounts",
                                                         "http://some.service.net/",
                                                         "Plain",
                                                         "arg1",
                                                         "arg2",
                                                         "arg3");
            });
```

I am getting Invalid cross thread error while i am creating the webbrowser control.

Comment: Why would you invoke a JS function through the `WebBrowser` when you could just call the the service from your code directly? That call can be made on a background thread, keeping the UI thread free.

Comment: Why your JS code is synchronous???? (Note that you've not shown it in the post).

Comment: I should consume it from JS only, that is the requirement. and JS call synchronous because of that my UI thread is stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is also generally shown when invoking java script method which does some stuff inside webpage like asynchronous call.

In my case it helped to call method this way:

I have taken the WB_LoadCompleted event to fire the invokescript method. You may modify it according to you needs.

```
    private void WB_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure the HTML document has loaded before attempting to
        // invoke script of the document page. You could set loadCompleted
        // to true when the LoadCompleted event on the WebBrowser fires.
        ActivateProgressIndicator(this, "hello");
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                //Give a call to your Browser.InvokeScript here. e.g.
                WB.InvokeScript("execScript", gestureHold);
            });
    }
```

Hope this helps you.
cheers

Comment: But this will stop my UI thread right, My main problem is Javascript function call is stopping UI thread, i am unble to see the UO untill the javascript function call completes.

Comment: Yeah.Right.
What you can do is :
Write a function. Let it have a dispatcher block as i wrote above. But just add a line to begin your progress bar display.
Then close this dispatcher.
outside the dispatcher but inside the funciton have the call to your InvokeScript. I hope that works.

Comment: No i have added my activate progress indicator function in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>{}); and added InvokeScript after dispatcher but still i am not able to see the UI untill the resopns came from the JS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gaurav, above are my comments. I am not able to solve my problem by following your above comments. Please can you look in to my comments and please help me..

Comment: I have modifyed the code snippet in my answer.
This thing worked well for me.
Hope it does work for you :P :)